# Jquery Ajax not working on server but working on localhost

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have the following jquery code that posts data to a php file and works fine on localhost. But when this code is now on the server the script returns an error instead of data.

```
  $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'scripts/info.php',
        data: {

            accountNumber: accountNumber,
            agentName: name

        },
        success: function( data ) {
            alert(data)
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            // check status && error
            alert(status)
        }
    });
```

This is the code in the php file that handles the post request:

```
$args0 = array(
'accountNumber' => $_POST['accountNumber'],
'dateReceived' => date("Y-m-d"),
'firstNames' => $_POST['agentName']    '
'regNumber' => $_POST['accountNumber'],
'surname' => $_POST['agentName']
);

try {
$client = new SoapClient(WSDL_URL, array(
    'trace' => 1,
    'exceptions' => true,
    'connection_timeout' => 300));

$params = array(
    'arg0' => $args0,

);


$client->__setLocation(WSDL_LOCATION);
$response = $client->upload($params);
$response = $client->__getLastResponse();

echo $response;
```

Please help

Comment: What's the console error?

Comment: I have been searching for the solution all over but i cannot find any solution

Comment: Is the php file on the same domain? Try console.log , instead of alert. Also try to just echo something simple like 'hello world' and see if the ajax get's that.

Comment: The php file is on the same domain

Comment: For example in your php file `echo 'hello world'; exit;` and then check your ajax to see if it returns the hello world, it's possible the rest of your code may not be working. You might have to add the full path to the php file in your ajax script

Comment: Getting nothing from the php file

Comment: Your PHP has a syntax error on the line `'firstNames' => $_POST['agentName']    '`.

Comment: `returns an error instead` ... what is the error?

Comment: @Pang - I'd guess it's a typo in the code here, since the OP claims the code works

Comment: @JaromandaX The OP also said `the script returns an error instead of data` and `Getting nothing from the php file`. Who knows.

Comment: He said it works in one host not on the other @pang

Comment: @JaromandaX So the reason could be that the OP introduced a typo before uploading on the server. Who knows.

Comment: True dat @pang still he says he gets an error but has chosen to keep the contents of the error message secret

Comment: @Deant You have a syntax error on the line `'firstNames' => $_POST['agentName']    '`. Are you sure this is your actual code? Also, are there any error messages that you're seeing? And what is the output of the PHP script? Please take a look at [**this page**] (http://stackoverflow.com/tags/php/info) to learn more on how to debug your issues. In particular, you may want to turn on error reporting on your server. Thanks.

Comment: Fixed the syntax error. But I'm still getting no response when I deploy to the server.

Comment: I am getting a xhr status 0. What can i do

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
    type:"post",
    url:"/pay/index.php?submit_order=yes",
    dataType:'json',
    data:{
        'rmb': $('#rmb').val(),
        'couponid': $('#cid').val(),
        'title' :$('#title').text(),
        'user' :$('#user').text(),
        'phone' :$('#phone').text(),
        'code' :$('#code').text(),
        'size' :$('#size').text(),
        'isinvoice':$('[name=isinvoice]').val()
    },
    beforeSend:function(){
        beforeSend.attr('disabled',true);
        beforeSend.html('submitting').removeAttr('href');
    },
    success:function(data){
        if(data.errorcode==1){
            $('.pay-fail').show().text(data.message);
        }else{
            if(data.url){
                location.href=data.url;
            }else{
                alert('post ok!');
            }
        }                      
    },
    error: function(){
        alert('submit error,then try again');
    }
})
```

This is my jQuery ajax for pay. It works on localhost and on server.